# razor: binding to list does not return altered values, binding to single property works fine

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am struggeling for days with that.

If I do this:

```
public string niente { get; set; }
```

and inside cshtml do this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Item.niente)
```

and then when I click on submit

```
<form action="@Url.Action("SaveEdit")" method="POST" id="idForm">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AutoCloseWindow)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Item.Id)
```

I am getting the values I typed into the textbox on the frontend.

BUT:
as soon as I put the property on a list

And add an element to it

```
    public List<string> niente 
    { 
        get 
        {
            List<string> res = new List<string>();
            res.Add("hi");
            return res;
        } 
    }
```

and then do the same thing but with an indexer:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Item.niente[0])
```

the value is displayed in the frontend ("hi")
but if I now alter the value in the frontend and write anything other to it, (like "hello") and then check my model after I clicked save:

[image]

The value is still "hi".
Again, when this object is not part of a list but a single property, I can alter them just fine.

I also tried observablecollection but to no avail

Please explain to me where my error is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue: As am instanting a list with the NEW keyword, it creates to instances of that list but binds to the correct one, however unbinds from the incorrect one.

So I had to make sure I only instantiated the list once. I did this inside the constructor. End of story.